# What is the word() function?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to convert some C++ function to use in my python script and stumbled upon this:

```
int Crc16(args...)
{
   // Some calulations

   return (int)word(~ByteHi,~ByteLow)
}
```

This is the end of a CRC16 calculator which I need, I have no idea what this return does? Especially the "word" function. The `~` is the Bitwise complement and the final number returned is a single integer. I didn't find anything on my search for this word() function. Could you help me?

Comment: `word` isn't a standard C++ function.

Comment: Needs proper context, i.e. what headers are included by the file you found this in (and the headers _they_ include, etc.) - can't be answered as-is.

Comment: Apparently it is used in this project: https://github.com/jrbenito/ABBAurora/tree/master/src in a cpp file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After viewing the project's readme, we know it's possible to be an Arduino related utils, then check the doc here:

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/conversion/wordcast/

> Description Converts a value to the word data type.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> word(x)
> word(h, l)
> (word)x (C-style type conversion)
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> ```
> x: a value. Allowed data types: any type.
> h: the high-order (leftmost) byte of the word.
> l: the low-order (rightmost) byte of the word.
> ```
>
> Returns Data type: `word`.

Answer (score 4):

From the usage you show, I would assume that it creates a 16 bit value from two bytes. It's not part of `c`/`c++` though. Probalby some function defined in your code.

```
uint16_t word(uint8_t hi, uint8_t low)
{
    return (hi << 8) + lo;
}
```

Comment: Why not `return (hi << 8) | lo` which might run faster and is more readable?

Comment: It's the same. You can also do it this way, it doesn't matter. Even the resulting code will most likely be the same. Why do you think it would be faster?

Answer (score 2):

It's not standard C or C++<sup>(a)</sup> but, given the context (CRC16 and the variable names), it almost certainly takes two 8-bit bytes and forms a 16-bit word.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Hence it's probably defined somewhere in the libraries or source code you have available to you.